# SelectOneMenu doesn't use the new Value

Tags: java, jsf

I got a problem described in the title. My selectOneMenu doesn't change my Value :/

```xml
<h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Vorgesetzter" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText
                            value="#{s.manager.surename}, #{s.manager.forename}"
                            rendered="#{not s.editable}" />
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{s.manager.userID}"
                            styleClass="inputlabel" id="Vorgesetzter"
                            rendered="#{s.editable}">
                            <f:selectItem
                            itemValue="${null}" itemLabel="-"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.userList}" var="us"
                                itemLabel="#{us.surename}, #{us.forename}"
                                itemValue="#{us.userID}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:commandButton value="bearbeiten"
                            action="#{sectionBean.switchEdit(s)}" 
                            rendered="#{not s.editable}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="speichern"
                            action="#{sectionBean.updateSection(s)}"
                            rendered="#{s.editable}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="abbrechen"
                            action="#{sectionBean.switchEdit(s)}"
                            rendered="#{s.editable}" />
                    </h:column>
```

this is a piece of the sections.xhtml. It's sourrounded by a form tag.

This is my bean:

```
package at.ac.htlperg.beans;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import at.ac.htlperg.dao.SectionDAO;
import at.ac.htlperg.model.Section;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SectionBean {
    SectionDAO sectionDAO;

public SectionBean() {
    sectionDAO = new SectionDAO();
}

public SectionDAO getSectionDAO() {
    return sectionDAO;
}

public void setSectionDAO(SectionDAO sectionDAO) {
    this.sectionDAO = sectionDAO;
}

public List<Section> getSectionList() {
    return sectionDAO.getSectionList();
}

public String deleteSection(Section s) {
    sectionDAO.deleteSection(s);
    return null;
}

public String switchEdit(Section s) {
    sectionDAO.switchEdit(s);
    return null;
}

public String saveSection() {
    sectionDAO.saveSection(sectionDAO.getSection());
    return "/secured/sealed/sections.xhtml";
}

public String updateSection(Section s) {
    sectionDAO.updateSection(s);
    this.switchEdit(s);
    return null;
}
```

}

the method updateSection should access the Database and does an session.update(s). 
But it doesn't save the new values, neither in the selectOneMenu, nor in the usual textbox above (not in the shown code).

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: A assume `s` in the xhmtl is a `Section`, so can you show its code? Also note that `s.manager.userID` would result in changing the user id of the manager not the manager of the section. This might not be supported by your model.

Comment: Are the model values been updated by JSF? Debug the content of `Section s` in the `updateSection()` method. What persistence API are you using? Hibernate? @Thomas this was also the first what I thought, but the OP also mentioned that "the usual textbox" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it helps, but in JSF 1.2 I had similar issues. The Problem was that h:selectOneMenu returned String values instead of Objects I suspected.

Maybe this "bug" wasn't solved for JSF2.0.

try something like:

```
// ManagedBean
String userId;

String getUserId(){return this.userId;}
void setUserId(String userId){this.userId = userId;}

// JSF
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBean.userId}"
                        styleClass="inputlabel" id="Vorgesetzter"
                        rendered="#{s.editable}">                            
    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.userList}" var="us"
                   itemLabel="#{us.surename}, #{us.forename}"
                   itemValue="#{us.userID}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and before working with `userId` convert it into the Object you want, or just try to use a converter.

Comment: This isn't a bug. This is by design. Java objects cannot be passed as HTTP request parameters without converting it to string first. Even then, this isn't the OP's concrete problem. OP's concrete problem has been nailed down in the comments of Thomas and myself on the question. However, as long as OP doesn't provide any feedback, it's impossible to give a suitable answer.